# How to ls the first file (path included) of every subfolder recursively?

Tags: awk, find, ls, uniq

Suppose these are the files:

```
folder1/11.txt
folder1/12.txt
folder1/levela/11a1.txt
folder1/levela/11a2.txt
folder1/levela/levelb/11b1.txt
folder1/levela/levelb/11b2.txt
folder2/21.txt
folder2/22.txt
folder2/levela/21a1.txt
folder2/levela/21a2.txt
folder2/levela/levelb/21b1.txt
folder2/levela/levelb/21b2.txt
folder3/a/b/c/d/e/deepfile1.txt
folder3/a/b/c/d/e/deepfile2.txt
```

Is there a way (for example using ls, find or grep or any gnuwin32 commands) to show the 1st file from every subfolder please?

Desired output:

```
folder1/11.txt
folder1/levela/11a1.txt
folder1/levela/levelb/11b1.txt
folder2/21.txt
folder2/levela/21a1.txt
folder2/levela/levelb/21b1.txt
folder3/a/b/c/d/e/deepfile1.txt
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting this solution:

```
find -type f -printf "%p %h\n"|sort --key 2.1,1.1|uniq --skip-fields=1|awk '{print $1}'
```

### Explanation:

#### `find -type -printf "%p %n\n"`

This `find` command search for all regular files under current directory.

And print for each file. Files' relative path,  (space), and files' relative folder.

Suggesting to run this command on your directory.

#### `sort --key 2.1,1.1`

Sort the files list lexicography, from 2nd field than 1st field
Result in all files are sorted per their specific directory

Suggesting to try this:

```
find -type f -printf "%p %h\n"|sort --key 2.1,1.1
```

#### `uniq --skip-fields=1`

From the sorted files list.

Remove those lines having duplicate directory (field #2)

#### `awk '{print $1}'`

Print only first field, the relative files path.

Answer (score 0):

A `bash` script:

#### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A filesArr  # declare assiciate array for files in directories
for currFile in $(find "$1" -type f); do # main loop scan all files undre $1
  currDir=$(dirname "$currFile")  # get the curret file's directory
  if [[ -z ${filesArr["$currDir"]} ]]; then # if current directory is not stored in filesArr
    filesArr[$currDir]="$currFile" # store the directory with curren file
  fi
  if [[ ${filesArr["$currDir"]} > "$currFile" ]]; then # if current file < stored file in array
    filesArr[$currDir]="$currFile" # set the stored file to be current file
  fi
done
for currFile in ${filesArr[@]}; do # loop over array to output each directory
  echo "$currFile"
done
```

#### Running `script.sh` on /tmp folder

```
chmod a+x script.sh
./script.sh /tmp
```

BTW: answer below with `sort` and `uniq` is much faster.